# How to overcome Asp.net MVC validation error for navigation property

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, model-validation

**Scenario:**

I am implementing Asp.Net MVC project with Entity Framework. I have following entities:

```
class Employee{
   public int Id{get;set;}
   [Required]
   public string Name{get;set;}
}

class Department{
   public int Id{get;set;}
   public string DepartmentName{get; set;}
   public virtual Employee manager{get; set;}
}
```

Now, I have to create new department that will have a manager from the list of employees in database. For this, view and controller actions are:

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.DepartmentName)
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.manager.Id, new SelectList(ViewBag.Managers, "Id", "Name"))


public class DepartmentController: Controller{
    private MyDatabaseContext db = new MyDatabaseContext();

    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Create(){
        ViewBag.Managers = db.Employees.ToList();
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create(Department d){
       if(ModelState.IsValid){
          d.manager = db.Employees.Find(d.manager.Id);
          db.Departments.Add(d);
          db.SaveChanges();
          return RedirectToAction("Index");
       }
       else{
         //error response.
         //Error encounters as d.manager.Name field would be null.
       }
    }
}
```

**Problem:**

When running above program, I cannot create new `Department`'s object, as the `ModelState.IsValid` is always `false`. The reason for this is that the navigation property `manager` has field `Name`, which would be `null` when submitting the form. As `Name` is required field, this would be listed as error.

**Question:**

How can I overcome the error due to `null` in field of navigation property? Or, is there other ways to implement this code so that I will get rid of this error?

**Notes:**

Please make note that I don't want to create different `ViewModel` merely useful for creating the `Department` object. I would prefer following DRY principle. 
Further, I don't want to create different field (something like, `managerId`) which would be foreign key to `Employees` table because I don't want the database associations taken care on the object oriented models. It's always cleaner to retrieve manager through `department.manager`, rather than reading manager object from entity framework by passing the `department.managerId` [Key] field.

Thank you.

Comment: As always, use a view model (it is the only realistic way to resolve your issue). It is not breaking the DRY principal.Every view, especially those for editing should have its own view model. Refer also [What is ViewModel in MVC?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11064316/what-is-viewmodel-in-mvc). And that view model should also contain an `IEnumerable<SelectListItem> ManagerList` so that you avoid using `ViewBag` and get strong typed binding.

Comment: I implemented a ViewModel in the way @StephenMuecke explained. This solution worked fine and the architecture and code also looks clean. However, still I have one question in my mind. In Spring MVC, we can put `@Valid` annotation for the navigation property, to make the framework to validate the navigation property as well. If we don't put `@Valid` annotation, then the framework doesn't perform validation, and we don't get any error. Do you know any such annotation/feature in Asp.Net MVC?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Please make note that I don't want to create different ViewModel merely useful for creating the Department object. I would prefer following DRY principle.

Using a view model in this case is not a violation of the DRY principle.  A view model represents a different concept (i.e. the data that your view requires).  That is an entirely different thing to the data your database table (domain model) requires.  If your view model and domain model happen to have the same properties when you initially implement them, that is *entirely coincidental*.

The DRY principle is about making sure you don't repeat the *same concept* in multiple places.

Using a view model is absolutely the correct approach, specifically, in your case, because it allows the validation requirements of your data access layer to vary independently of the validation requirements of your UI layer.  By reusing your domain model in your UI, you lose the flexibility to do this, and you'll constantly run into the same issue you're describing.

Comment: Thank you for making strong points in your answer. I am now convinced why using ViewModels is reasonable in the case of the question.

Answer (score 1):

You need this

```
public int EmployeeId {get;set;}
```

on Department.

Comment: Yes, this approach works fine to overcome the error. However, let us figure out if there are other ways too to solve the problem, without modifying the models/entities. I mean, from perspective of domain model design, I am not comfortable adding database related fields in model. I prefer letting the entity framework take care of this.